# How to create an image from an python script (using docker sdk) running in docker container?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile

I have two dockerfiles, test and result. A python script running in test container has to create the image for result using docker sdk. I have both the dockerfiles and the python script for test copied into the workdirectory of the test. However when i get an error in test script saying No such file or directory.

Dockerfile of test:

```
FROM python:3.7.2-slim
WORKDIR /test
COPY . /test
RUN pip install docker 
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/test"
CMD ["python", "test.py"]
```

test.py:

```
// dockerfile of result is named result
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
image = client.images.build(path="/test", dockerfile='result') 
container = client.containers.run(image)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do

```
COPY . /test
```

You copy everything of folder that is docker-compose.yml.

But when you are in test.py probably you are in another folder.
So you need to back levels of folder to acess /test.

Comment: I'm not using Docker Compose

Comment: If you can try it with docker compose, maybe it could help you.